# Why does this not print the String inside the object?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

This program is used for a flash card application. My constructor is using a linked list, but the problem is that when I use a method that list the cards inside a specific box it is not printing the desired result. The system should print "Ryan Hardin". Instead it is printing "Box$NoteCard@68e86f41". Can someone explain why this is happening and what I can do to fix this? I have also attached both my box and note card classes.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Box {

public LinkedList<NoteCard> data;

public Box() {
    this.data = new LinkedList<NoteCard>();
}

public Box addCard(NoteCard a) {
    Box one = this;

    one.data.add(a);

    return one;

}

public static void listBox(Box a, int index){

    ListIterator itr = a.data.listIterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NoteCard test = new NoteCard("Ryan", "Hardin");
    Box box1 = new Box();
    box1.addCard(test);

    listBox(box1,0);

}
}
```

This is my NoteCard Class

```
public class NoteCard {

public static String challenge;
public static String response;


public NoteCard(String front, String back) {

    double a = Math.random();
    if (a > 0.5) {
        challenge = front;
    } else
        challenge = back;
    if (a < 0.5) {
        response = front;
    } else
        response = back;
}


public static String getChallenge(NoteCard a) {
    String chal = a.challenge;
    return chal;
}

public static String getResponse(NoteCard a) {
    String resp = response;
    return resp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NoteCard test = new NoteCard("Ryan", "Hardin");

    System.out.println("The challenge: " + getChallenge(test));
    System.out.println("The response: " + getResponse(test));
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not getting the right result. There could be only one object in the list according to you.

Comment: Have you implement method toString inside NoteCard? Can you please add the NoteCard class

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/e3HKY4

Comment: @saikumar It should print the front and back of the note card. Instead it is printing "Box$NoteCard@68e86f41"

Comment: @ShadowDroid It should print the front and back of the note card. Instead it is printing "Box$NoteCard@68e86f41"

Comment: @RyanHardin please follow the answer given and may be this answer will come in handy [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20735223/3526330)

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the method toString() in your `class NoteCard`.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
  //Format your NoteCard class as an String

  return noteCardAsString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In First place you are making too much use of `static keyword`. I am not sure whether you need that. 
**Anyways create two instance variable front and back and assign value to it in constructor of NoteCard class, Also implement toString method**

```
public class NoteCard {

public static String challenge;
public static String response;
public String front;
public String back;


public NoteCard(String front, String back) {
 //your code
 this.front = front;
 this.back = back;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
  //return "The challenge:" + challenge + " " + "The response: " + response;
  return "The Front:" + front + " " + "The Back: " + back;
}
```

> Note: Since the instance method toString() is implicitly inherited
>   from Object, declaring a method toString() as static in a sub type
>   causes a compile-time error SO DON'T MAKE THIS METHOD STATIC