# Printing An Empty Array

Tags: java, arrays

In order to test a program I wrote these statements:

```
public class asdf{
  public static void main(){
    int arr[] = new int[5];
    System.out.println(arr);
  }
}
```

The output I got was:

```
[I@1df6ed6
```

Is this a garbage value or something different?

Comment: I'm no java expert, but it occurs to me you might have to convert the array to a string before you print it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when printing an object in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735132/what-happens-when-printing-an-object-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is being printed is the [memory address](http://javapapers.com/core-java/address-of-a-java-object/) of the object. In order for the object to print a human-readable string it has to have `toString()` implemented in such a way that it is human-readable. Memory addresses will change each time you execute a program, and are generally represented in a way that is not particularly useful (unless you're doing deep magic with the operating system).

One way to get this is to use the [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility to convert each element of the array to a `String`.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but it's really the [identity hash code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)), which is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

The "garbage value" is actually the address of the array (where it is stored in memory).

If you want to print the contents, you need to first `import java.util.Arrays;` and then

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

Comment: I actually wanted to know what is [I@1df6ed6 as I have never encountered this before. So does this value have a name.

Comment: It is simply the address of the array. It points to the array in memory. In Java, this will probably have little use for you.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794930/why-does-printing-a-java-array-show-a-memory-location).

Comment: Actually as ricky pointed out below, it's not technically the address, but the hash.